# rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.2]

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I am using the command as below

```
rsync -a --ignore-existing  /users/phd/muzafarwan/WRF   muzafar@cseprojxxx.xxx.xxx.ac.in:
```

and the error I am getting is as below

> rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
> rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.2]

Answer (score 3):

Please read the error message carefully. It says *exactly* what the problem is.

Remember that rsync over ssh works by running rsync and both ends, and having them communicate over a secure ssh tunnel. Rsync has to be installed on local and remote end.